# Returning JSON reponse in Django from a specific function

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I just started with Django today, I'm trying to get a JSON response from a certain function I have and save it all into database

This is my function code:

```
import nmap

def nm_scan(ip):
    nm = nmap.PortScanner()
    nm.scan(ip, '0-65535')
    for host in nm.all_hosts():
        print('----------------------------------------------------')
        print('Host : %s (%s)' % (host, nm[host].hostname()), 'State : %s' % nm[host].state())
        for proto in nm[host].all_protocols():
            lport = sorted(nm[host][proto].keys())
            for port in lport:
                print('port : %s\tservice : %s' % (port, nm[host][proto][port]['product']))
```

I have my `urls.py` ready like so.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('scan/', views.nm_scan),
]
```

So I'm trying to understand how I would pass the parameter which would come in `/scan/:ip` and pass it to my function as parameter, then return the JSON data

I have tried looking at some sample codes but I'm still stuck with just nonsense such as

```
def nm_scan(request, ip):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    data = JSONParser().parse(request)
    # rest of the function here
```

If someone could help me it would be great. Thanks.

Comment: You need to understand the Django router, i.e. how Django maps urls to views and passes the dynamic arguments in the url to your view. The best place to learn this is to actually do the full [Django starter tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/) and in part 3, you'll see how to write patterns for passing parameters to views. Or read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/) to jump directly to the documentation for the URL dispatcher.